# How to render JSX inside a HTML tag attribute? (getting [object Object])

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a function that returns JSX and I need the HTML output to fill a `data-tooltip` attribute, needed by jQueryUI to render tooltips.

But React is rendering `[object object]` rather than HTML inside the `data-tooltip` attribute:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.hello = this.hello.bind(this);
  }

  hello() {
    return (
      <p>Hello</p>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p data-tooltip={this.hello()}>Hi</p>
        <p>{this.hello()}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In this example, the second `this.hello()` works, and HTML is returned, which proves that the `hello` function properly uses JSX. But the first `this.hello()` call results in `data-tooltip="[object object]"`.

**How to insert HTML inside a tag attribute?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, neither return HTML, but a React element. However, in the second case the JSX compiler 'knows' what to do with the element, and React knows how to render it into the DOM.

I'm not sure whether you could insert HTML inside the tag attribute, but you could generate HTML from the component using [renderToString()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.